# Delete from tasks where project.find(project_id) is null

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

The title of this question is a very rough version of the query that I'd like to execute.

I've deleted project tasks without a user id,  and I now want to delete tasks related to the projects that I've just deleted.  Of course I probably should have just done it all with one query ... will take any suggestions for that query also,  because I will be using it in future.

But for now,  I need to delete project tasks which have a non-existent project associated ... i.e. a project_id that has no project associated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: Test this query on a test database first. I claim no responsibility for data lost by running this query against production data.

`DELETE t FROM project AS p LEFT JOIN tasks AS t ON (p.id = t.project_id) WHERE p.id IS NULL`